# Automatic Bootup

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, automation

Is there any way I can make my old laptop, a HP Pavilion dv2225la, boot up automatically say at 7:00 each morning? I know I can shut it down automatically, but boot up? Does anyone have any ideas? It's got Windows 7.

Thanks

Comment: Your [notebook manual](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01035657.pdf) isn't very precise about its options. All I found was point 1.3 » Power management » Setting customization by the user. Have a look in your BIOS whats behind this option. Otherwise your laptop supports network boot. Maybe this can be combined with a [wake-on-lan packet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN)

Comment: @nixda what do you mean by combining thw wol with the network boot? I asked the question on here because then manual didn't says anything much! thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the options under your BIOS power management? All we can do is to read your manual. Its up to you to look there or wait until someone with that old laptop comes around. (The second possible solution with "Wake on LAN" will only work if your laptop is permanently connected with an Ethernet cable to a router or second PC.)

Comment: There's no way to do this. What I'm doing instead is only hibernating it, then waking it up, which can be all done automatically. Then on mondays, a auto restart happens after the wake up.

Answer (score 1):

This is a function of your laptop's BIOS.

On one of my older machines, there was a BIOS option to specify a wakeup alarm. It power up the machine at the specified time, using the motherboard RTC (realtime clock).

Go into your BIOS and look around for this kind of functionality.